# Why isn't there Israel nuclear talk?

Tags: international-law, israel, iran, nuclear-weapons, proliferation

Iran is suspected of building nuclear weapons, then world powers hold Iran nuclear talks in order to prevent them from obtaining nuclear weapons.

Meanwhile Israel most likely already has nuclear weapons (for example, when asked if Israel has nuclear weapons, John Kerry said "sure. everybody's common knowledge"), but why is there no such talk to force Israel abandon their nuclear weapons?

Comment: Both this post and your last one have been arguments, not questions; your question presumes that having a problem with Iran's nuclear program logically implies that one should have a problem with Israel's nuclear program.

Comment: Both this comment and your last one are trying to surppress the questions, not addressing the questions; they presume that a questions is not a legitimate one if I don't like it or can't answer it

Comment: These are not questions suitable for the politics SE. They aren't even really questions, they are arguments. You are free to ask what countries stances are on the Israeli nuclear program and why they hold them, but when you try to make an argument justifying why countries should hold a certain stance, you're making an argument, not asking a question.

Comment: That's about the worst position I could take short of actual president, so thanks. I'm more of a policy wonk myself.

Comment: Actually, this is also a duplicate http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/236/is-there-any-objective-reason-why-some-states-can-have-nuclear-weapons-but-other?rq=1

Comment: @Avi It isn't a duplicate. this question is primarily about Israel's nuclear talks, not the whole world.

Comment: Re: [surppress the questions]. In order this question to become *a question*, it must, at minimum, contain prooflinks supporting the statements within. With it, the question becomes valid and **answerable**. Without it, the question is nothing but a bunch of bareword accusations that invite for denials (usually, also bareword ones). See the comments above for a proof.

Comment: Downvoting for unreferenced claims.

Comment: @bytebuster by prooflinks you mean the English websites? because that's not gonna work in all situations :)

Comment: @Saeed yes, the English ones. The key is the ability **to answer your question**, so we need to understand it first. Think what would happen if you ask the question in Persian *and someone else answers you in Hebrew, Hindi, or Chinese*. The same applies to quotes: each claim (of an official person) is made in some **context**, and a good prooflink will also let us know the context. Let's at least stick to a single language.

Comment: @bytebuster That still doesn't mean something in English websites is more trustworthy than something written in Persian websites. there is no reason you should trust English websites more than Persians. everything on the Internet can be changed. I can setup a totally legitimate website in few hours and add whatever i want into it then give you the link as a prooflink and you can't deny it because that will be a total discrimination and this site will be more corrupt than it currently is.

Comment: @saeed bytebuster clarified his reasoning, so this is a total strawman. English is necessary so people understand it, not because it is more reputable.

Comment: @Avi I was talking about English text too. very clear

Comment: There is no "most likely" here. Israeli nuclear capabilities are recognized and occasionally discussed in the mass media, even if diplomatically Israel supposedly doesn't own up to it.

Comment: Who says there isn't? https://www.jpost.com/international/article-720993 ; https://www.foxnews.com/world/un-committee-votes-israel-dispose-nuclear-weapons-allow-international-inspectors

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**From a legal perspective:**

Israel hasn't signed the [Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons). Iran did sign the treaty and got the benefits from it - so Iran trying to get a nuclear weapon or not cooperating with the International Atomic Energy Agency to prove otherwise is a breach of the treaty.

**From a political / practical point of view:**

Israel most probably has owned nuclear weapons for decades. However, the other countries in the region don't freak out because of this, thus it doesn't threaten the relative stability of the region.
The Iranian nuclear program is different. Iran supports a handful of extremist groups or groups directly opposing the acting government in various countries in the region (the most notable example as of now should be those in Yemen). That's essentially part of Iran's foreign policy which is how they gain and exert influence over the region. It's an effective and well thought out policy to become one of(?) the most influential countries in the region but on the other hand it makes Iran the number one hated entity in the region (and yes, despite all the loud talks, it is not Israel, as it was also shown in the wikileaks). 
So if Iran were to acquire nuclear weapons putting them in a position of undeserved authority, then all the Arab countries in the region would recognize this as a direct threat - not simply because Iran would bomb them but because it could help them  support their local enemies and put pressure them. No suprise that e.g. the Saudis would try everything to convice the US to bomb the Iranian nuclear facilities and even [offer their airspace for Israel to help them bomb Iran](http://www.foxnews.com/world/2010/06/12/saudi-arabia-gives-israel-clear-skies-attack-iranian-nuke-sites/)

So should Iran gain nuclear weapons then

- this would be a clear sign that the Non-Proliferation Treaty means nothing and that could give ideas to other countries who signed the treaty
- most probably would destabilize the middle-east region
- and the Arab countries in the region would most probably answer (among others) by launching their own nuclear programs.

Comment: I totally agree with the Legal perspective because that's the truth but the rest of your answer is mostly opinion based.

First of all, Iran is a peaceful country, Israel is not. Saudis (by borrowing troops from other countries) are trying to take over a totally legitimate country like Yemen and are bombing and killing millions of innocents and yet no country is trying to help them, except Iran. it is totally a humanitarian behavior against terrorists like Saudis. why doesn't America help them if they support peace in ME?

Comment: Second, Israel for a long long time has been killing innocents in Palestine (specially children) and stealing and taking over their houses and building their own cities instead. so Israel is more motivated to bomb Palestine than any other countries. and your total assumption of Iran and its defensive/offensive measures are completely wrong. It's not an abandoned place where you can launch any successful airstrike, nuclear missile and things like that. You don't know anything about Iran's foreign policy, Intelligence and defense or attack mechanism so better provide a more believable answer.

Comment: To say Iran supports extremist groups and Israel doesn't is a bit disingenuous. You *could* say Israel is more stable politically, but I think there are plenty of valid arguments that could be made towards Israel also supporting extremist groups.

Comment: @blip such as? The leaders of the Arab countries in the region made clear that they see Iran as a threat due to it's proxies. On the other hand they quite clearly don't see the already nuclearly equipped Israel as a threat to their rule. Thus they are quite clearly frustrated by the prospect of a nuclear Iran while we quite clearly don't see the same reaction toward the Israel. And that's the point.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61364/discussion-on-answer-by-david-herskovics-why-isnt-there-israel-nuclear-talk).

Comment: @user2977 (1) as you are probably already aware by now, Iran is meddling all across the ME (including Yemen), (2) your views on Israel are highly biased; Israel does not intentionally hurt civilians, and especially not children. Any casualties in armed conflicts are because the Palestinian terrorists fire from within their own population (as a strategic decision; they can't win on the military front so they try to win on the media). regardless, Israel would not use a nuclear weapon on the Palestinians because (a) it's not necessary, (b) it's way way too close and would be very harmful to IL)

Comment: @user2977: duh, Israel using a nuke on the Palestinians is extremely improbable due to the proximity of the fallout to their own population, all other considerations aside, like surely losing massive US aid if they did something like that. OTOH when Saddam was threatening to hit Israel, possibly with chemical weapons, the Israeli counter-threat was quite more ambiguous. Something about watching Iraqi cities 45 minutes later.