# What benefit did Iran gets out of signing nuclear proliferation treaty?

Tags: iran

[why is there no Israel nuclear talk?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8761/why-is-there-no-israel-nuclear-talk)

says that Iran signed that agreement while Israel didn't.

What did Iran get out of that agreement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be brief: Iran gained her nuclear program through joining first the Atom For Peace program then the NPT.

Iran's nuclear program was launched during the shah's rule and was heavily supported by the US and later on also by France and West Germany.

They provided the knowledge, the access to the technology, the highly enriched uranium, they built the facilities.

For Iran to get these benefits she needed to make the commitments to not attempt to gain nuclear weapons.

Answer (score 2):

Iran has been able to get and keep Russian investments in its nuclear program. Had Iran not been part of the NPT then Iran would have had to build the Bushehr reactor all by itself.

Comment: Iran built most of their advanced equipment, centrifuges e.g IR-8, reactors etc. by himself and they are not limited only to nuclear facilities but that's not your problem not knowing any of this. all you get on the news is how much Iran hates Israel. what you can't see doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -2):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons):

> The [Non-Proliferation Treaty] is often seen to be based on a central bargain: “the NPT non-nuclear-weapon states agree never to acquire nuclear weapons and the NPT nuclear-weapon states in exchange agree to share the benefits of peaceful nuclear technology and to pursue nuclear disarmament aimed at the ultimate elimination of their nuclear arsenals”.

Comment: Yes, but what does "share the benefits of peaceful nuclear technology" mean in practice? What tangible, specific benefits did they get by signing the treaty which they couldn't get without?

Comment: Precisely. So Iran is getting a bad deal. Also the shah is gone. US can declare that the new iraq is a totally new country and forgive the debt. Iran may also say that the the Iran now is a totally new country.

Comment: @SharenEayrs If a country doesn't plan to have nuclear weapons then it's a real good deal - you get the benefits without losing anything you wanted. Of course, if the country does plan having nuclear weapons then there is a trade-off, but not otherwise.

Comment: @SharenEayrs the Iraqi debt toward the US is a matter between Iraq and the US. The US can decide to annul the debt with no problem - but not the Iraqis. The NPT is an international treaty. Maybe if all countries in the treaty were to decide that Iran would be exempt from its own part from the treaty then it may be legally possible to do this - but that woul make the whole treaty pointless.